# Use IsolatedStorageFile or the WritableSettingsStore?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vsx, vsix

I'm making a visual studio 2010 extension and need some storage to store some settings like: a list of recent files, ui control state, some user preferences, etc...

Which should I use, and why?

the [WritableSettingsStore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28MICROSOFT.VISUALSTUDIO.SETTINGS.WRITABLESETTINGSSTORE%29;k%28WRITABLESETTINGSSTORE%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK%2cVERSION%3dV4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true) or the [IsolatedStorageFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.IO.ISOLATEDSTORAGE.ISOLATEDSTORAGEFILE%29;k%28ISOLATEDSTORAGEFILE%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK%2cVERSION%3dV4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are both viable.  I'm currently using isolated storage to store settings for both a vsx and related control designers.

I can tell you that it works perfectly fine.  Once implemented, I haven't had to go back and change anything or fix corner case bugs.

If I were to do it over again... I'm not sure if I would go with ISF or the WSS.  WSS has the advantage of being *built for use by visual studio extensions*, which means it is bulletproof.  But the API is a bit harder to deal with.

Your choice should be based on which is easier for you to implement and support.